# How to change Ag Grid border color?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Does anyone know is it possible to change Ag Grid component border color?
I was trying to do remove it with styling `ag-theme-alphine`

```
<div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: '100%', borderColor: 'white', fontSize: '1vw',}}>
```

But it doesn't work at all. Also i tried to do it with css, but again no luck.

```
.ag-root-wrapper {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: red;
    border-color: var(--ag-border-color, #babfc7);
}
```

Comment: try ` border-color: var(--ag-border-color, #babfc7) !important;` to override theme

Comment: you are overriding the border-color, try using !important

Comment: Thank you it worked with !importent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css `!important` to override theme default styles.

See bellow:

```html
.ag-root-wrapper {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: var(--ag-border-color, #babfc7) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed border color of Ag-Grid component with CSS, it works only when '!important' is used.

```
.ag-root-wrapper {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-color: var(--ag-border-color, #fffff) !important;
}
```